# Installing Crown Molding - Metal Studs

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I'm thinking about putting up crown molding in my living room, but the apartment building I live in has steel studs. I've seen people online use the x method of nailing to secure the crown molding to the drywall itself. Do you think this would be enough support to hold the weight of the crown molding?

I've also read about using self-tapping screws but that would be much more difficult and more permanent, since the room is large and the ceilings are very high.

Any advice or recommendation is appreciated!

Comment: You characterize your abode an an apartment. This suggests that you are a renter and some landlord actually owns and manages the property. If you are a renter and do not own the property then you should not be thinking about putting up crown molding in your living room. As a minimum you would want to read your rental agreement and then consult with the landlord. The property owner would have the say as to how molding would be installed if it was allowed - not obscure folks on the internet.

Comment: Many people own their apartments through condo or co-op schemes.

Comment: At that point it is no longer an "apartment" but a "condo". I only know USA terminology, but "Apartment" specifically means rented/non-owned.

Comment: [#6 x 2-1/4 in. Fine Phosphate-Plated Steel Trim Flat Head Square Screws](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Grip-Rite-6-x-2-1-4-in-Fine-Phosphate-Plated-Steel-Trim-Flat-Head-Square-Screws-214STHDW1/100154569)

Comment: Put a board that will fit behind the crown moulding on the wall and put a screw into the studs through it. Then install crown nailing at will to this board

Answer (score 1):

Questions about rental/landlords aside, you could X nail with some construction adhesive and as long as your crown isn't huge (less than 5"), it should stay up fine.

If I was doing this, I'd have temporary bracing (1x2s would be fine) while the glue sets, and add plenty of nails wherever the crown looks loose against the wall/ceiling.

One last tip you didn't ask for... when I do crown, I center it on the wall, shoot the middle to pin it in place, then do the corners with a bit of scrap (cut to the other side of the corner) to tweak the angle perfectly. If you have to twist a lot to make the corners right, then pin the corners and then pull the middle off and do over. If you just have to twist a tiny bit, then keep nailing. Twisting works much better on mdf than wood, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase mouldings that are made out of foam. They are pre-finished and are extremely light (compared to wood) and are ideal for situations where you need to x-nail.

I've used it in a basement remodel where we used steel studs.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Lease & pending your Landlord signing an Addendum that you won't have to remove them. Then actually, Super Sticky or Heavy Duty Velcro squares are an excellent 1-time option.

I say 1-time because they'll rip the paint & primer right off if you want to adjust them, so don't & just putty or caulk open corners & the top & bottom seams (if desired). But, you can just put up new Velcro squares to re-mount & you won't be able to tell any difference from nailed, screwed or glued.